# Find a isoperimetric inequality for a curve which contains a ball

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, divergence-operator

Let $C$ be a simple, compact, connected curve and $\Omega$ its inner domain. Let supose that $\Omega$ has a ball of radius $r$. Prove a inequality involving the area of $\Omega$: $A(\Omega)$ and and the length of $C$:L  but L can not appear squared or having any power.

I managed to prove that in a different problem with the curve inside a ball getting $$ A(\Omega) \leq \frac{r}{2}L, $$ just by using divergence theorem. Any idea for this?

Comment: For clarity, you should make it clear that everything's going on in the plane. So you get something out of the usual isoperimetric inequality, and I'd be surprised if you can do any better. From $L^2\ge 4\pi A\ge 4\pi^2 r^2$, we get $L\ge 2\pi r$, not so interesting.  ... I do not understand at all what you wrote about the different problem. If the curve is *inside* a disk of radius $r$, it can have length as close to $0$ as you want. So that inequality seems impossible. Clearly something's not stated correctly.

Comment: The other problem is in page 350 of this book https://books.google.es/books?id=dHDzpBDHPigC&pg=PA350&lpg=PA350&dq="A(Ω)≤r2L"&source=bl&ots=WWuvhi5c2G&sig=vH9nsZ5c0HnK3ztaSbHONU_qHeM&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio5vDrprLXAhWCcBoKHUvfBfIQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22A(%CE%A9)%E2%89%A4r2L%22&f=false , and I need something similar in a curve with a disk inside

Comment: Oh, I forgot in the second problem that $\Omega$ was the domain with boundary curve $C$.